# How to connect edges to make a cut

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to cut drawers into a sideboard that I'm attempting to model. I've already figured out how to extrude them inwards into the main part of the sideboard, except it has some details on the front and I can't seem to find a way to cut the faces that aren't parallel to the Y axis (basically the sides of the details). Adding edge loops doesn't work because I'm trying to cut in a straight line, and the edge loops are crooked like the face itself. Boolean modifiers and knife project also don't work. This is my first time modeling something and I'm genuinely at a loss here, I don't know what to do.

EDIT: [I've uploaded the file as per crazycourier's suggestion.](https://file.io/JrjxJ0BjBxvg)
[image]

[image]

Comment: A boolean should work, unless the mesh that you're working on is messed up. Try uploading your blend file so people can take a look.

Comment: I've tried and it didn't work. But since it's my first modeling it's not like I really know what I'm doing so the mesh being messed up is possible lol I've uploaded it! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your mesh was a little bit messed up, but don't let it discourage you! The distorted bars that run down the front, the mesh on those looks to have been duplicated over themselves. So there were multiple vertices/edges/faces taking up the same space which can cause lots of problems!!

In edit mode, I selected everything and then went to Mesh > Merge > By Distance, which merges verts within a tolerance (can you set this).
[image]

That removed a ton of vertices and cleaned it up a bit.

[image]

Then I just added a boolean, set to the fast solver and BOOM. Works!
[image]

Here's a Blend file with the working Boolean.
[image]

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO MUCH!! I had an idea that it had a lot of duplicated vertices/edges but I hadn't figured out how to properly work the remove doubles tool. And you've really helped me out. Thank you for uploading the file! I'm trying to fix my own by following the steps you've described and by using your file as reference, but the boolean still doesn't work. I'm trying to figure it out though. Thank you so much for your help, it's really been a godsend.

Comment: Try the different solvers on the boolean modifier. Both Fast and Exact to see if that fixes it. Also, hovering over a mesh with your cursor and pressing "L" will select all the connected pieces of that mesh. Try selecting pieces and separate them "P", to their own objects. Then try the boolean on each of those to try and troubleshoot where your problem is. Good luck!